# Extract part of string using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, awk

**Strings:**

```
"v1.0.20170728180812 latest ef1fc15"
"latest ef1fc15 v1.0.20170728180812-test"
"ef1fc15 v1.0.20170722150727 latest"
```

---

**Expected string result:**

```
"v1.0.20170728180812"
"v1.0.20170728180812-test"
"v1.0.20170722150727"
```

Code:

```
string='latest ef1fc15 v1.0.20170728180812-test'
replace=$(echo $string | sed 's/v.*$//g')
echo $string | sed -e 's/$(echo $replace)//g'
```

Thanks guys! ;)

This script is used to get a valid version of the aws ecr, and deploy it to kubernetes only with --apply (avoiding caching when used "latest").

**Complete Code:**

```
ecrVersions=$(aws ecr describe-images --repository-name <ECR_REPO_NAME> --image-ids imageTag=latest --output text)
appVersion=$(echo $ecrVersions | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) {if($i~/^[v]/){print $i}}}')
echo $appVersion
```

Comment: Show us the code...

Comment: string='latest ef1fc15 v1.0.20170728180812-test'

replace=$(echo $string | sed 's/v.*$//g')

echo $string | sed -e 's/$(echo $replace)//g'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
 awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) {if($i~/^[v]/){print $i}}}' yourfile.txt
```

This is:

1. Iterating the file record by record (because that's what awk does)
2. Iterating each field delimited by the default : `for (i=1;i<=NF;++i)`
3. Testing to see if the field starts with a "v": `if($i~/^[v]/)`
4. If so it prints the field value `print $i`

I'm certain sed could make quick work of this too.

Answer (score 1):

*POSIX* shell code.  Cut off the `v` and whatever's before it, (then add a `v` to replace the missing one), then cut off any  and whatever's after it:

```
string=v"${string##*v}"
string="${string%% *}"
```

Demo:

```
for string in "v1.0.20170728180812 latest ef1fc15" \
              "latest ef1fc15 v1.0.20170728180812-test" \
              "ef1fc15 v1.0.20170722150727 latest"; do 
    string=v"${string##*v}"
    string="${string%% *}"
    echo $string
done
```

Output:

```
v1.0.20170728180812
v1.0.20170728180812-test
v1.0.20170722150727
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk match function：

```
awk '{match($0,"v[0-9][^\" ]+",a);print "\""a[0]"\""}' file
```

Comment: `echo 'latest ef1fc15 v1.0.20170728180812' | awk '{match($0,"v[0-9][^\" ]+",a);print "\""a[0]"\""}' 

`awk: line 1: syntax error at or near ,`